# dpdk-devbind execute failed in pod container

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, dpdk, podsecuritypolicy

I am trying to bind vfio-pci driver to sriov vfs in k8s pod container，but got an error print

```
#./dpdk-devbind.py -b vfio-pci 0000:19:02.1
Error: unbind failed for 0000:19:02.1 - Cannot open /sys/bus/pci/drivers/iavf/unbind.
# echo "0000:19:02.1" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/iavf/unbind
bash: /sys/bus/pci/drivers/iavf/unbind: Read-only file system
```

But dpdk-devbind.py can works in another docker container created by `"docker run --privileged "`,
I thinks this is maybe the `PodSecurityPolicy` issue.
After I create PodSecurityPolicy with `"privileged: true, readOnlyRootFilesystem: false"`, the issue still exist, I was confused.

Why dpdk-devbind.py can not works in k8s pod container with privileged ?
 should I move the binding operation to host? but some apps runs in container really want to pick the sriov VFs and bind the vfio-pci driver.

Also, the `KNI` can not works well.

```
KNI: Failed to open file: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vEth0_0/carrier.
```

update: `insmod rte_kni.ko carrier=on`, then comment code `rte_kni_update_link()` can fix KNI issue

**update**: according to [Kubernetes volumes not getting mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926638/kubernetes-volumes-not-getting-mounted/61938522#61938522), use `initContainers` to mount host `/sys` to pod `/sys rw`, now dpdk-devbind.py can works .

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you running DPDK devbind script with `sudo` privilege or not?

Comment: @ Vipin Varghese, with root privilege

Comment: Hmm, with proper debug I am not able to root cause the issue. Only one option is to ensure the `0000:19:02.1` is  down `ifconfig [vf interface name] down`, then unbind from iAVF. Let me know if you are up and availble for a debug.

Comment: @VipinVarghese, thanks for your reply, this issue have been closed,  use `initContainers` to mount host /sys to pod /sys rw, now dpdk-devbind.py can works, thanks